# Microsoft Outlook Express 6: how to create a distribution list?

Tags: email, contacts, outlook-express, distribution-list

Microsoft Outlook Express 6:  How can I create an email distribution list?

Also, what is the difference between a `contact group` and a `distribution list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the same as Office Outlook then open your addresss book and select File > New Entry > Distribution List

And this is a quick description of groups and distribution lists but it says they are much the same thing:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/grouping-contacts-HA010266586.aspx

Answer (score 1):

- Click Tools -> Address Book
- Click New -> New Group
- Create a name, click Select Members for existing contacts or New Contact.

Voila!